# Why does getter get called when map is called

Tags: javascript

Here is the Javascript code:

```
class MyArray extends Array {
    // Overwrite species to the parent Array constructor
    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Array;
    }
}

var myArray = new MyArray(1, 2, 3);
var mapped = myArray.map(x => x * x);
```

When myArray.map is called, it in turn calls the static getter (get) in the MyArray class. Why does it do this? What is causing it to be called? Something internal to map?

Comment: If you were intentionally using `Symbol.species`, I'd expect you had an idea what it does?